# why CefGlue.Demo.WinForms OnTooltip never being called,but it displayed in the demo

Tags: winforms, tooltip, cefglue

when I debug the CefGlue.Demo.WinForms ,Tooltip displayed ,but how it works?
Anybody can help?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, this method is not called for windowed browsers [CEF issue #783](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/783), but should be called for windowless browsers.

Also you don't specify version.

PS: StackOverflow is not tracked by valuable part of CEF community, so [CEF forum](http://magpcss.org/ceforum) is the best place to ask questions about CEF. Also most questions ends up 'whats version and etc...'. It is not very good fits into QA style.

Comment: Thanks for the warning.